# Website for grain bill determination by style

Tags: ingredients, beer-styles

I have not been able to find a website that lists percent of each malt and/or adjunct for a given style of beer.  Is there such a site?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure you're going to find anything besides recipes that are especially prescriptive about what goes in to the beer. Check out [BeerSmith](http://beersmithrecipes.com/), [BrewToad](https://www.brewtoad.com/), and other sites to find some recipes. They will give you some concrete examples of grain bills for a style.

If you're looking for something more broad, check out the [BJCP style guidelines](http://www.bjcp.org/stylecenter.php), especially the [style guide with ingrediant comments](http://www.bjcp.org/docs/2015_Guidelines_Consolidated.pdf). These are much more general and illustrate that most styles have a wide range of acceptable ingrediants.

Comment: BrewTarget, too! Free and good recipes.